jQuery.js inclusion and conflicts with Slider Revolution
ou hava some jquery.js libaray include that come after Slider revolution file js inclustion. 1 set the module general option ->jquery and output filters -> js to body to on . 2 find the double jquery.js inclusion and remove it.
I try pluging of Asset Cluen
